# Error: no method matching iterate(::Expr)

Tags: macros, julia, mapping

```
macro superM(arg, argc)

    map(foo,argc)
end

@superM test {1,2}
```

I just want to passe the argument `argc` to the map function, but I'm getting this error: `no method matching iterate(::Expr)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `argc` is an Expression whose `head` is braces `{}`:

```
julia> dump(:({1, 2}))
Expr
  head: Symbol braces
  args: Array{Any}((2,))
    1: Int64 1
    2: Int64 2
```

so what you really want is the `args` field of the expression `{1,2}`

```
julia> macro superM(arg, argc)    
           map(identity,argc.args)
       end
@superM (macro with 1 method)

julia> @superM test {1,2}
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
```